# Converting standart objects to App::FeaturePython in Freecad

Tags: python, freecad

I want to be able to add custom properties to objects in Freecad. I was able to add it via "obj.addProperty()", but it works only on objects of type "App::FeaturePython". When I try it on, for example "PartDesign::Pad", I get this error: "RuntimeError: Type PartDesign::Pad cannot dynamically add properties".

Is there any way how to add custom properties to standart objects like "PartDesign::Pad", or how to convert the standart objects to something that can  take custom properties?

The properties values should be lists or dictionaries of strings and / or doubles.

Thanks.